# Fluentd tail Plugin : a nested output

Tags: regex, fluentd

I read a file and got a record as "Taipei", then I want to format it to mongoDB below:

```
{"asia":   {"city":"Taipei"} }
```

I tried using "." , but it not working

```
 format /^(?<asia.city>[^ ]*)/
```

what is the correct regex , or I should try another plugin?